# Proj.NET transform wkt to lat lon coordinate list

Tags: coordinate-system, c#

I am looking to transform from a WKT in 27700 into lat lon list of coordinates, but cannot quite work out how to do it using this library:

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=projnet

I can easily do a single easting/northing point like this:

```
    public static double[] EastNorthToLonLat(double easting, double northing, CoordinateSystem fromCS)
    {
        var convertFrom = CS27700;
        switch (fromCS)
        {
            case CoordinateSystem.Epsg27700:
                convertFrom = CS27700;
                break;
            case CoordinateSystem.Epsg4326:
                convertFrom = CS4326;
                break;
            case CoordinateSystem.Epsg3857:
                convertFrom = CS3857;
                break;
        }

        var trans = new CoordinateTransformationFactory().CreateFromCoordinateSystems(convertFrom, CS4326);
        var result = trans.MathTransform.Transform(new[] {easting, northing});
        return result;
    }
```

I have seen this so I preume this has something to do with it, but I can't work out how to call the transform with the WKT, all it takes is the array of coordinates:

```
var fromCS = CoordinateSystemWktReader.Parse(wkt) as ICoordinateSystem;
```

My ulltimate is to get it into a format like this:

[[-0.165,51.185] , [-0.16,51.180], [-0.265,51.584]] etc